# Нужен перевод в некоторых местах в профиле

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

- [Во вкладке с вопросами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=questions):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- [Во вкладке с ответами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=answers):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переводы добавил. Ожидаем на сайте в новых сборках.

Текущая rev 2022.2.8.41404